CTRL+X / CTRL+C a control breakes the code
in simple words , i have a working button
 Private Sub btnHarvester1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If cash <= 0 Then
        Else
            cash -= 1000
            Label4.Text = "Cash : " & cash
            WheatHarvester += 1
        End If
    End Sub

i ctrl + X the button to move it to tabpage2 , it stopped working , i double click the button to see whats wrong , and i get this
   Private Sub btnHarvester1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHarvester1.Click

    End Sub


nothing i can do , since i have no idea what the problem is ..

a guy just told me that cutting a control removes the handles not just moving the controls , and the same guy also told me to use document outline to move controls , now everything works perfectly !
